# Nested comments from scratch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I have a comment model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :replies, class: "Comment", foreign_key: "reply_id"
end
```

I can show a comment instance`s replies in a view like so:

```
comment.replies do |reply|
   reply.content
end
```

However, how do I loop through the replies of the reply? And its reply? And its reply ad infitum? I'm feeling we need to make a multidimensional array of the replies via class method and then loop through this array in the view.

I don't want to use a gem, I want to learn

Comment: Where'd you store the reply's replies?

Comment: How many levels of replies do you have

Comment: Arguably infinite. I'm thinking that when I have so many replies though I stop indenting. But from the functionality point of view, infinite.

Comment: What is the entity related with the comment? What do you comment on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems like what you have is one short step away from what you want. You just need to use recursion to call the same code for each reply as you're calling for the original comments. E.g.

```
<!-- view -->
<div id="comments">
  <%= render partial: "comment", collection: @comments %>
</div>

<!-- _comment partial -->
<div class="comment">
  <p><%= comment.content %></p>
  <%= render partial: "comment", collection: comment.replies %>
</div>
```

NB: this isn't the most efficient way of doing things. Each time you call comment.replies active record will run another database query. There's definitely room for improvement but that's the basic idea anyway.

Comment: But can I still build on this idea? Last night I had the eureka moment of using a recursive partial like this, shame this wouldn't be efficient. Would creating a named scope or something make this more efficient?

Comment: One way to make it more efficient would be to [pre-load the children](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations). I.e. the replies, for each record. I'm not sure how the AwesomeNestedSet mentioned in woahdae's answer does things but if you're trying to learn it might be worth downloading the source and reading it to investigate.

Comment: Ah yes, the old n+1 problem, easy enough to get around, I'll probably just do this to be honest...

Comment: Somehow I doubt that the efficiency problem is completely solvable if you're using SQL. If you're concerned about performance you might want to consider using something like mongo which is more suited to this problem. You could keep all the comments in one document/record and they'd all be loaded at the same time. What you lose is the ability to easily use them in multiple places (e.g. same comment on multiple articles), but I don't think you want to do that so it's worth considering.

Comment: I think to do this in one query by hand, what you'd need to do is store some kind of heirarchial id index that has all the parent ids in order with the first one first. So if I had a leaf comment with id 5, the parent had id 2 and its parent had id 1 then my index would be "1-2-5" or just "1-2" maybe. Then when you load comments you can load them all at once because you know that everything that has that column starting with 1- relates to comment 1.

Comment: @jeanaux the problem is solvable via SQL in a number of ways, especially if you're using a modern database like Postgres that supports recursive queries. [This blog post](http://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/recursive-sql-in-activerecord) from a google search has everything you could ask for.

Comment: Also, the parent id string is the approach Ancestry takes, if you're looking for precedent.

Comment: @jeanaux What you are describing is along the lines of a Closure Table.  An excellent set of slides on various SQL tree structures by Bill Kawin is here: http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data

Comment: @woahdae that's a really awesome solution actually, why didn't you post it as an answer? And it's good to know it's easy to get the functionality I mentioned from the gem, although OP did specify they wanted it from scratch so it would probably be worth explaining that more in depth in your answer too with the gem as a side note.

Comment: +1 for closure_tree. as long as a comment has a parent_id, you can access comment.children plus a boatload of other methods. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 3):

Would using a nested set still count as 'from scratch'?

The short description of a nested set is a database-specific strategy of querying hierarchies by storing/querying pre- and post-order tree traversal counts.

[A picture is worth a thousand words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aNestedSetModel.svg) (see also, [the wikipedia page on nested sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model)).

[There are a bunch of nested set gems](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Active_Record_Nesting), and I can personally speak for the quality of [Awesome Nested Set](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set) and [Ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry)

Then, Awesome Nested Set (I know from experience, presumably Ancestry too) provide helpers to do a single query to pull up all records under a tree, and iterate through the tree in sorted depth-first order, passing in the level while you go.

The view code for Awesome Nested Set would be something like:

```
<% Comment.each_with_level(@post.comments.self_and_descendants) do |comment, level| %>
  <div style="margin-left: <%= level * 50 %>px">
    <%= comment.body %>
    <%# etc %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I just made that up from vague memories, and it's been a while, so this is where it can be "an exercise for the reader"

Answer (score 3):

My approach is to make this done as efficient as possible.
**First lets address how to do that:**

1. DRY solution.
2. Least Number of queries to retrieve the comments.

Thinking about that, I have found that most of the people address the first but not the second.So lets start with the easy one.
we have to have partial for the comments so referencing the answer of [jeanaux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22635981/nested-comments-from-scratch#22709494)

we can use his approach to display the comments and will update it later in the answer

```
<!-- view -->
<div id="comments">
  <%= render partial: "comment", collection: @comments %>
</div>

<!-- _comment partial -->
<div class="comment">
  <p><%= comment.content %></p>
  <%= render partial: "comment", collection: comment.replies %>
</div>
```

We must now retrieve those comments in one query if possible so we can just do this in the controller. to be able to do this all comments and replies should have a commentable_id (and type if polymorphic) so that when we query we can get all comments then group them the way we want.

So if we have a post for example and we want to get all its comments we will say in the controller.
@comments = @post.comments.group_by {|c| c.reply_id}

by this we have comments in one query processed to be displayed directly
Now we can do this to display them instead of what we previously did

All the comments that are not replies are now in the @comments[nil] as they had no reply_id
(NB: I don like the @comments[nil] if anyone has any other suggestion please comment or edit)

```
<!-- view -->
<div id="comments">
  <%= render partial: "comment", collection: @comments[nil] %>
</div>
```

All the replies for each comment will be in the has under the parent comment id

```
<!-- _comment partial -->
<div class="comment">
  <p><%= comment.content %></p>
  <%= render partial: "comment", collection: @comments[comment.id] %>
</div>
```

**To wrap up:**

1. We added an object_id in the comment model to be able to retrieve
   them( if not already there)
2. We added grouping by reply_id to
   retrieve the comments with one query and process them for the view.
3. We added a partial that recursively displays the comments (as
       proposed by [jeanaux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22635981/nested-comments-from-scratch#22709494)).

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you need a self-referential association. Check out the following railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association

Comment: The relationship is 'posts' has_many `replies`. There's no has_many has_many stuff going on here, however I still need a join table?

Comment: but it seems that replies also have many replies, right? So there is som has_many has_many stuff going on.

Answer (score 2):

We've done this:

[image]

We used the [`ancestry`](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) gem to create a hierarchy-centric dataset, and then outputted with a partial outputting an `ordered list`:

```
#app/views/categories/index.html.erb
<% # collection = ancestry object %>
<%= render partial: "category", locals: { collection: collection } %>

#app/views/categories/_category.html.erb
<ol class="categories">
    <% collection.arrange.each do |category, sub_item| %>
        <li>
            <!-- Category -->
            <div class="category">
                <%= link_to category.title, edit_admin_category_path(category) %>
                <%= link_to "+", admin_category_new_path(category), title: "New Categorgy", data: {placement: "bottom"} %>

                <% if category.prime? %>
                    <%= link_to "", admin_category_path(category), title: "Delete", data: {placement: "bottom", confirm: "Really?"}, method: :delete, class: "icon ion-ios7-close-outline" %>
                <% end %>

                <!-- Page -->
                <%= link_to "", new_admin_category_page_path(category), title: "New Page", data: {placement: "bottom"}, class: "icon ion-compose" %>
            </div>

            <!-- Pages -->
            <%= render partial: "pages", locals: { id: category.name } %>

            <!-- Children -->
            <% if category.has_children? %>
                <%= render partial: "category", locals: { collection: category.children } %>
            <% end %>

        </li>
    <% end %>
</ol>
```

We also made a nested dropdown:

[image]

```
#app/helpers/application_helper.rb
def nested_dropdown(items)
    result = []
    items.map do |item, sub_items|
        result << [('- ' * item.depth) + item.name, item.id]
        result += nested_dropdown(sub_items) unless sub_items.blank?
    end
    result
end
```

Answer (score 2):

That can be solved with resursion or with a special data structure. Recursion is simpler to implement, whereas a datastructure like the one used by the `nested_set` gem is more performant.

### Recursion

First an example how it works in pure Ruby.

```
class Comment < Struct.new(:content, :replies); 

  def print_nested(level = 0)
    puts "#{'  ' * level}#{content}"   # handle current comment

    if replies
      replies.each do |reply|
        # here is the list of all nested replies generated, do not care 
        # about how deep the subtree is, cause recursion...
        reply.print_nested(level + 1)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Example

```
comments = [ Comment.new(:c_1, [ Comment.new(:c_1a) ]),
             Comment.new(:c_2, [ Comment.new(:c_2a),
                                 Comment.new(:c_2b, [ Comment.new(:c_2bi),
                                                      Comment.new(:c_2bii) ]),
                                 Comment.new(:c_2c) ]),
             Comment.new(:c_3),
             Comment.new(:c_4) ]

comments.each(&:print_nested)

# Output
# 
# c_1
#   c_1a
# c_2
#   c_2a
#   c_2b
#     c_2bi
#     c_2bii
#   c_2c
# c_3
# c_4
```

And now with recursive calls of Rails view partials:

```
# in your comment show view 
<%= render :partial => 'nested_comment', :collection => @comment.replies %>

# recursion in a comments/_nested_comment.html.erb partial
<%= nested_comment.content %>
<%= render :partial => 'nested_comment', :collection => nested_comment.replies %>
```

### Nested Set

Setup your database structure, see the docs: http://rubydoc.info/gems/nested_set/1.7.1/frames That add the something like following (untested) to your app.

```
# in model
acts_as_nested_set

# in controller
def index
  @comment = Comment.root   # `root` is provided by the gem
end

# in helper
module NestedSetHelper

  def root_node(node, &block)
    content_tag(:li, :id => "node_#{node.id}") do
      node_tag(node) +
      with_output_buffer(&block)
    end
  end

  def render_tree(hash, options = {}, &block)
    if hash.present?
      content_tag :ul, options do
        hash.each do |node, child|
          block.call node, render_tree(child, &block)
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def node_tag(node)
    content_tag(:div, node.content)
  end

end

# in index view
<ul>
  <%= render 'tree', :root => @comment %>
</ul>

# in _tree view
<%= root_node(root) do %>
  <%= render_tree root.descendants.arrange do |node, child| %>

    <%= content_tag :li, :id => "node_#{node.id}" do %>
      <%= node_tag(node) %>
      <%= child %>
    <% end %>

  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This code is from an old Rails 3.0 app, slightly change and untested. Therefore it will probably not work out of the box, but should illustrate the idea.

Answer (score 1):

This will be my approach:

- I have a Comment Model and a Reply model.
- Comment has_many association with Reply
- Reply has belongs_to association with Comment
- Reply has self referential HABTM

  ```
  class Reply < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :comment
    has_and_belongs_to_many :sub_replies,
                    class_name: 'Reply',
                    join_table: :replies_sub_replies,
                    foreign_key: :reply_id,
                    association_foreign_key: :sub_reply_id

    def all_replies(reply = self,all_replies = [])
      sub_replies = reply.sub_replies
      all_replies << sub_replies
      return if sub_replies.count == 0
      sub_replies.each do |sr|
        if sr.sub_replies.count > 0
          all_replies(sr,all_replies)
        end
      end
      return all_replies
    end

  end
  ```

  Now to get a reply from a comment etc:
- Getting all replies from a comment: @comment.replies
- Getting the Comment from any reply: @reply.comment
- Getting the intermediate level of replies from a reply: @reply.sub_replies
- Getting all levels of replies from a reply: @reply.all_replies

Answer (score 0):

I've had various generally bad experience with the different hierarchy gems available for ActiveRecord. Typically you do not want to do this yourself as your queries will end up being very inefficient.

The Ancestry gem was ok, but I had to move away from it because 'children' is a scope and NOT an association.  This means you CANNOT use nested attributes with it because nested attributes only work with associations, not scopes.  That may or may not be a problem depending on what you are doing, such as ordering or updating siblings through the parent or updating entire subtrees/graphs in a single operation.

The most efficient ActiveRecord gem for this is the [Closure Tree](https://github.com/mceachen/closure_tree) gem and I had good results with it, with the caveat that splatting/ mutating entire sub-trees was diabolical because of the way ActiveRecord works. If you don't need to compute things over a tree when doing updates then it is the way to go.

I've since moved away from ActiveRecord to Sequel and it has recursive common table expression (RCTE) support which is used by its built-in tree plugin. An RCTE tree is as fast as is theoretically possible to update (just modify a single parent_id as in a naive implementation) and querying is also typically orders of magnitude faster than other approaches because of the SQL RCTE feature it uses. It is also the most space efficient approach since there is just parent_id to maintain.  I am not aware of any ActiveRecord solutions that support RCTE trees because ActiveRecord doesn't cover nearly as much of the SQL spectrum that Sequel does.

If you're not wedded to ActiveRecord then Sequel and Postgres is a formidable combination IMO.  You will find out the deficiencies in AR when your queries become ever so slightly complex. There is always pain moving to another ORM as its not the out of the box stock rails approach but I have been able to express queries that I couldn't do with ActiveRecord or ARel (even though they were pretty simple), and generally improved query performance across the board 10-20 times over what I was getting with ActiveRecord. In my use case with maintaining trees of data its hundreds of times faster.  That means tens to hundreds times less server infrastructure I need for the same load. Think about it.

Comment: Please add examples of queries you can't do in AR

Comment: I really love AR to pieces so I hope Andrew's not right :(

Comment: @khaled_gomaa AR/Arel can't perform intersection, union all, or join conditions, RCTE queries or stored procedures in AR/ARel. Even doing OR conditions is difficult or problematic as is composing scopes that perform joins. You can work around some things but not others, the SQL escape clause doesn't always return a result that can be chained either. If you take a look at the SQL standard which Postgres largly supports and see what AR and Arel provide you will notice a very large gap. Do the same with AR vs Sequel and you will notice how much more SQL support there is.

Comment: @Starkers  I didn't want to change ORM's initialy but was forced to because of some pretty nasty problems that surfaced in my use of AR 4 plus I just couldn't express queries like I can with Sequel.  All I can say is that Sequel was the best decision and is hands down a much cleaner and powerful data access layer than anything else available for Ruby. It has allowed so much more flexibility and use of some awesome postgres features (eg array associations, and embedded rows/types) and I don't need as many gems to fill in the gaps.

Comment: @khaled_gomaa I also forgot window functions and full text search.

Answer (score -1):

You'd collect the reply's replies within each Reply iteration.

```
<% comment.replies do |reply| %>
   <%= reply.content %>
   <% reply_replies = Post.where("reply_id = #{reply.id}").all %>
   <% reply_replies .each do |p| %>
     <%= p.post %>
   <% end
<% end %>
```

Though im not sure if it'd be the most conventional way cost-wise.

Comment: This stops after the first level of replies, replies to replies (etc) will not show.